# Xcode 8 simulator ios 8 image get distorted

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode8-beta6

I just get this bug,some images on the iOS 8 simulator get distorted.iOS9,and iOS10 don't have this bug.
I'm not sure that this is a Xcode 8 bug,or this is my problem.

[image]

Comment: I am also having this problem. It only happens in iOS 8. Already submitted a bug report to Apple. [![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mpRNi.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mpRNi.png)

Comment: Thanks for submitting it. It would be great to share Apple's answers here.

Comment: They asked me to provide more detailed information. I will post their answers once they confirmed the issue.

Comment: Thanks! I guess it's a combination of the asset-catalog and iOS8. Images that are not stored in there not seem to be affected.

Comment: Did you receive an update on the above issue? It's a blocker for releasing iOS 10 apps for us.

Comment: Apple hasn't replied yet. I have sent several messages to Apple but no feedback yet.

Comment: apple tells me " We tried to reproduce this and could not."

Comment: see if I can reproduce the problem using a new project and zip to them...

Comment: @PrimaryChicken too late for that, the GM is already out :-(

Comment: The GM build fixed this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same here, this seems to be a valid Xcode-issue. It is only happening on iOS 8 sims and only with the latest Xcode 8 Beta 6. We should file a bugreport for this.

Comment: This problem also happens in device.