# Xcode 8 beta 6 - App image broken in iOS 8

Tags: ios8, xcode8-beta6

I have Installed Xcode 8 beta 6 and deployed the app into iOS 8 - 10 device to test.

I found some app images are broken in iOS 8 device (Please refer to the image shown below)

[image]

It works perfectly fine in iOS 9 and iOS 10

[image]

Is it a bug from Apple? Anyone having the same problem? Many thanks.

Possible duplicate to : [Xcode 8 simulator ios 8 image get distorted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972093/xcode-8-simulator-ios-8-image-get-distorted/39094802#39094802)

Update: Xcode 8 GM build fixed this problem

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issues too.  I found that the same image on iPhone 4s was distorted but not on iPhone 6s.  So I then tested it by disabling the 1x and 2x asset for the same image. It then started working on iPhone 4s.  I hope Apple fixes this issue in the gold master.

Answer (score 0):

Same here! There is a pending bug report in the other ticket, hopefully Apple will react and fix this in the next Beta iteration.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is back in Xcode 9.2

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW936

"Workaround: Build the app using Xcode 9.1, or use Xcode 9.2 and set the deployment target to iOS 8.4 or later."

Another more involved workaround is to delete the image from Images.xcassets and add the image(s) back in directly to the bundle.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this :).